# resize transparent image in opencv python (cv2)

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-resizing

I have an image with shape (120, 470, 4) and I want to resize it to another size e.g. (100, 400, 4).
I try to achieve it by using `cv2.resize` function as bellow

`reshaped_image = cv2.resize(image, (100, 400))`

and paste the reshaped_image inside a bigger transparent image, but the problem is reshaped_image has the shape (100, 400, 3) instead of (100, 400, 4).

Is there something wrong I'm doing or the `cv2.resize` function will lose transparency information?
And at last I'll be pleased to know about your solution. (with simple example if possible)

regards

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example which loads a 3 channel image, takes its blue channel and copies it as alpha channel (which makes no sense at all, but I had no 4 channel image at hand) and merges it again as a 4 channel image. Then this image is resized.

If you load a 4 channel image, the flag -1 indicates that the image is loaded unchanged, so you can load and split all 4 channels directly.

Shapes of all images are printed, and resizing works. I am working opencv version 3.1.0.

Hope that helps.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('image.jpg', -1)
print img.shape

b_channel, g_channel, r_channel = cv2.split(img)
alpha_channel = b_channel 
print b_channel.shape
print g_channel.shape
print r_channel.shape
print alpha_channel.shape

img_RGBA = cv2.merge((b_channel, g_channel, r_channel, alpha_channel))
print img_RGBA.shape

res = cv2.resize(img_RGBA,(100, 400), interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
print res.shape
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, but is there some way to do it in lower versions of cv2? I currently use 2.4.8 and the resize function give me a 3 channel image after resizing.